# How do I compile a dll with R and RCPP?

Tags: c++, r, mingw, rcpp

I have written a .cpp file and I want to compile it to a .dll for use with R and RCPP. (without using the inline package).
I am using WinXP and R 2.13.2 and RCPP 0.9.7. I am using Rtools 2.14.

1. How do I include Rcpp.h in minGW's search path? I underastand that the files that I need to include are in C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.2\library\Rcpp\include. However, I was not able to add the to "add" them to "search path".
2. I tired a temporary "hack". I copied the contents of C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.2\library\Rcpp\include into minGW's include directory. The compiling/linking process gets from myfile.cpp to myfile.o but throws a bunch of errors before it can compile myfile.dll.

I have added C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.2\bin\i386 to my PATH and I am calling R CMB SHLIB myfile.cpp from the WinXP command prompt.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of quick points:

1. The `gcc` and `g++` compilers from MinGW behave just like other compilers from the `gcc` family. That means there is no 'add to search path': you use the `-I/some/dir` switch to add that path and directory. Similarly, `-L/some/lib` adds that directory to the linker path.
2. You *really* want to use a `Makefile`.  Our [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) packages comes with lots of examples; you could look at the `Makefile` in the `ConvolveBenchmarks` directory.
3. But what you really want is to use so-called "package". We have an entire vignette [Rcpp-package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-package.pdf) devoted to this. It can be as simple as calling the `rcpp.package.skeleton()` function which creates the package for you---and the dynamic library gets created as a side-effect.
4. If all this is too confusing, try getting familiar with [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) first.  Use the `verbose=TRUE` argument to see how [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) builds the dynamic library!
5. Lastly, we spell it [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html), not RCPP.

The `rcpp-devel` mailing list is a good source of help too.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I have encountered an error when trying to replicate the 'inline' example from your journal of statistical software paper. 
I am running the following code:
 src <- '
   Rcpp::NumericVector xa(a);
   Rcpp::NumericVector xb(b);
   int n_xa = xa.size(), n_xb = xb.size();
  
   Rcpp::NumericVector xab(n_xa + n_xb - 1);
   for (int i = 0; i < n_xa; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < n_xb; j++)
   xab[i + j] += xa[i] * xb[j];
   return xab;
   '
fun <- cxxfunction(signature(a = "numeric", b = "numeric"),src, plugin = "Rcpp", verbose=TRUE)

Comment: I get the following errors:
Compilation argument:
 C:/R/R-2.13.2/bin/i386/R CMD SHLIB file99a82.cpp 2> file99a82.cpp.err.txt 

ERROR(s) during compilation: source code errors or compiler configuration errors!

Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! 
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/R/R-2.13.2/bin/i386/R CMD SHLIB file99a82.cpp 2> file99a82.cpp.err.txt' had status 1

Comment: Where do I find this 'file99a82.cpp.err.txt ' to read the actual error messages?

Comment: As I wrote in my initial answer, I would suggest that you subscribe to rcpp-devel and post there.

Comment: Where is the DLL located after `rcpp.package.skeleton()` is run?