# Rcpp, making functions available to R from DLL

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

New to C++, I would like to make functions compiled in a DLL available in R.

So far, I managed to do that for a basic function taking `integer` as input and returning the same, by following [these steps](https://erpcoder.blog/2016/06/15/how-to-develop-a-c-dll-for-r-in-visual-studio-2015/) in VisualStudio, then using `dyn.load` from R to load the created dll.

However, my C++ functions will need to handle R `data.frame` objects, and I am not sure how to make that possible. I saw from [the Rcpp gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/modifying-a-data-frame/) that `Rcpp` might include some kind of translations between R and c++ data types including `data.frame` objects, but I don't know if I can generate a dll using `Rcpp` that I can then include in R using `dyn.load`.

From [this answer by Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735661/5224236), it seems possible to generate a "dynamic library" using `Rcpp`, however, I could not find any dll when I tried generating a package with a source `.cpp` file using `rcpp.package.skeleton()`. The function I'd like to have a dll for is from [the Rcpp gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/modifying-a-data-frame/)

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame modifyDataFrame(DataFrame df) {
  // access the columns
  IntegerVector a = df["a"];
  CharacterVector b = df["b"];

  // make some changes
  a[2] = 42;
  b[1] = "foo";       
  // return a new data frame
  return DataFrame::create(_["a"]= a, _["b"]= b);
}
```

I tried to just paste that code into VisualStudio to try and generate that DLL, however I have the error "cannot find Rcpp.h" which I quite expected.

I then followed these steps in RStudio:

1. Create new project / Package
2. Include this cpp source file as a source file for this package
3. `include` Rcpp and enter `Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackage")` so far, no DLL in the package folders
4. Tried to build the package in RStudio by going to Build/Install and Restart, but then I get an error message "Building R Packages needs installation of additional build tools, do you want to install them?" However I already have RbuildTools 3.4 installed, and when I click "YES" in RStudio nothing happens.

PS: Happy to hear about other methods but here the DLL format should be used if possible. Any piece of info is greatly appreciated since I have basically no idea of how Rcpp or C++ work

Comment: First off: Where in our copious documentation do we ask you to use _Visual Studio_ ?  Correct answer, nowhere. In fact the Rcpp FAQ explicitly says not to.  Second:  `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` creates _sources_ whereas a DLL is the result of a _compilation and link_ step.  Did you compile and link?

Comment: The reason I used VisualStudio is that I haven't found yet in your copious documentation how to make functions available in a standalone DLL - if I missed that point, please point me to the right source, thanks

Comment: 1. Create a package containing to-be-compiled source code, eg via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.  2. Build the package, eg via `R CMD build` and `R CMD INSTALL` (or by hitting buttons in RStudio).  If between steps one and two you copy a valid file in the `src/` directory, it will be part of of the package shared library. _That is how R works_ and has nothing to with Rcpp per se.  Also note that only of of the OSs that R is used on defines the term "DLL".  So don't obsess over it -- Linux and macOS will call it a shared library file with extensions `.so` and `.dylib`, respectively.

Comment: And most importantly:  Don't make up your own rules (ie: "compile with Visual Studio") and expect things to work like that.  The world does not owe you that favour.

Comment: I am not trying to make up any rules at all, just using what I found on the net. I am here to humbly request help and clarifications, but I'm going to ask you to abstain if you are to use such a tone. I am sure we both have a lot of shit to deal with outside of StackOverflow

Comment: Instead of repeating the same question over and over, why don't you *read* my comment from seventeen minutes ago which has the answer?  You assumption is still wrong so "you're still making up your rules".  It doesn't work that way.  `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` is *not* the function that compiles and links and hence *not* the one creating a shared library.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel it's not super clear but I think the OP wants to have the result of their work be a DLL that they can use _in other projects_, i.e. not from R but in other compiled code, Windows executables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work:

1. from R, ran `Rcpp.package.skeleton("dfcpp4", cpp_files="modifyDataFrame.cpp")`. The second argument is required in order for the `modifyDataFrame` function to be available from the `dll` using `dyn.load`.
2. From the command line ran `R CMD build dfcpp4`
3. ran `R CMD check dfcpp4 --no-manual` from the command line.
4. The `dll` file in now present in the `src-x64` folder

I am now able to call this function using

```
dyn.load("dfcpp4/src-x64/dfcpp4.dll")
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3),
                 b = c("x", "y", "z"))
.Call("_dfcpp4_modifyDataFrame", df)
   a   b
1  1   x
2  2 foo
3 42   z
```

What I don't get is why in this case `.Call` should be used instead of `.C`...

Comment: For Pete's sake please read a modicum of Rcpp docs -- for example the [updated Rcpp Introduction vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf). You do *not need* to call `dyn.load()` yourself.  You do *not need* to call  `.Call()` yourself.  Rcpp Attributes and its code generators that all for you.  Look eg at package [RcppExamples](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples).

Comment: Just call `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` after you copied that C++ file into `src/`. It will updated `src/RcppExports.cpp` and `R/RcppExports.R`.  Once you build and install you should now have `modifyDataFrame()` *directly callable from R*.

Comment: Please read the question, I do **not** want to install a package at this point, I just want to use the dll.

Comment: You still misunderstand. The dll does not matter. It is a by-product. It is made for you and remains hidden in the package, or the tools (ie `Rcpp::cppFunction()`). Your issue may be your point 4) above: correct your RStudio / Rtools setup and it all becomes a breeze.  No point running around angrily til that is fixed -- you are wasting your time, and ours unless we just ignore you.

Comment: This might not be how you intended Rcpp to be used, but still my question is as valid as any other - plus it taught me few (small) things about a) how Rcpp works and b) what not to talk about on stackoverflow :) If that'll make it easier for you then be sure that I will learn more about your great work and use it in the intended way as long as this way also meets my requirements

Comment: If you want to decompose the commands look at the old examples with package `inline` instead, and maybe some of my old slide decks from 2009 to 2012 or so -- still posted on my site.  They have all the old-style examples.  If you must, you can. *It is still "wrong" to manually call `dyn.load()` because you now introduce an OS dependency we currently do not have.*  Your call.

Comment: And/or: Ignore Rcpp.  Read just _Writing R Extensions_ and learn a C extension. Generalize to a C++ extension.  Then redo it in one quarter of the code using Rcpp _for either C or C++_.  Good learning exercise if you have the patience, and good fodder for a blog post.  Now, *here* we focus on simpler answers to help others who may stumble upon them.  Cheers.

Comment: Ok! keep you posted

Answer (score 3):

You need to figure out why your setup is hosed.  This is *meant to be easy* and it is easy.  Watch:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction('DataFrame modDF(DataFrame df) { IntegerVector a = df["a"]; CharacterVector b = df["b"]; a[2] = 42; b[1] = "foo"; return DataFrame::create(Named("a")=a, Named("b")=b); } ')                  
R> df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=letters[24:26])                                                                                                                                                                       
R> df                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  a b                                                                                                                                                                                                              
1 1 x                                                                                                                                                                                                              
2 2 y                                                                                                                                                                                                              
3 3 z                                                                                                                                                                                                              
R> modDF(df)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   a   b                                                                                                                                                                                                           
1  1   x                                                                                                                                                                                                           
2  2 foo                                                                                                                                                                                                           
3 42   z                                                                                                                                                                                                           
R>
```

Now, I obviously don't recommend writing this way in a long one-liner. *You are already on the right track* setting up a package.  But you need to sort out what is holding up your tools.

And as a PS the one-liner above with better indentation:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction('DataFrame modDF(DataFrame df) { \
      IntegerVector a = df["a"]; \
      CharacterVector b = df["b"]; \
      a[2] = 42;  \
      b[1] = "foo"; \ 
      return DataFrame::create(Named("a")=a, Named("b")=b); \
    } ')
```